# The trace of the $\sigma$-algebra of all $\mu^*$-measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathcal X, \mu)$ be a measure space. Let $\mu^*$ be the [outer measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_measure#Method_I) induced from $\mu$. Let $\mathcal{M}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra of all $\mu^*$-measurable sets. Let $(X, \overline{\mathcal X}, \overline \mu)$ be the [completion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure#Construction_of_a_complete_measure) of $(X, \mathcal X, \mu)$.

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of pairwise disjoint sets in $\mathcal X$. Let $\mathcal X_n$ be the sub $\sigma$-algebra that $\mathcal X$ induces on $X_n$, i.e., $\mathcal X_n := \{A \cap X_n : A \in \mathcal X\}$. Let $\mu_n$ be the restriction of $\mu$ to $\mathcal X_n$, i.e., $\mu_n (A) := \mu (A)$ for all $A \in \mathcal X_n$. We construct the corresponding objects $(\mu^*_n, \mathcal M_n, \overline{\mathcal X_n}, \overline{\mu_n})$ from the measure space $(X_n, \mathcal X_n, \mu_n)$. Then we have

> **Lemma** $\mu_n^* (A) = \mu^* (A)$ for all $A \subset X_n$.

The proof of the **lemma** is given at the end. Now I would like to prove the following analogue, i.e.

> **Theorem** $\mathcal M_n = \{A \cap X_n : A \in \mathcal M\}$.

Could you have a check on my attempt?

---

**Proof** We have $\mathcal{M}$ is the collection of all those sets $A \subseteq X$ such that
$$
\mu^*(E)=\mu^*(E\cap A) +\mu^*(E\cap (X \setminus A)) \quad \forall E\subset X.
$$

- Let $A \in \mathcal M$. Let's prove that $A_n := A \cap X_n \in \mathcal M_n$. Let $E\subset X_n$. Then $E \subset X$. So
  $$
  \begin{align}
  \mu^*(E ) &= \mu^*(E\cap A) +\mu^*(E\cap (X \setminus A)) \\
  &= \mu^*(E\cap A_n) +\mu^*(E\cap (X_n \setminus A)) \text{ because }  E \subset X_n\\
  &= \mu^*(E\cap A_n) +\mu^*(E\cap ((X_n \setminus A) \cup (X_n \setminus X_n))) \\
  &= \mu^*(E\cap A_n) +\mu^*(E\cap (X_n \setminus (A \cap X_n))) \\
  &= \mu^*(E\cap A_n) +\mu^*(E\cap (X_n \setminus A_n).
  \end{align}
  $$
  It follows from the **Lemma** that $\mu_n^*(E ) = \mu_n^*(E\cap A_n) +\mu_n^*(E\cap (X_n \setminus A_n)$.
- Let $A' \in \mathcal M_n$. Let's prove that there is $A \in \mathcal M$ such that $A' = A \cap X_n$. It suffices to prove that $A' \in \mathcal M$. Let $E \subset X$. I [proved previously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4608028/the-construction-from-outer-measure-of-the-completion-of-a-measure-space) that $\mathcal X \subset \mathcal M$. Then  $X_n \in \mathcal M$ and thus
  $$
  \mu^*(E) = \mu^*(E\cap X_n) +\mu^*(E\cap (X \setminus X_n)).
  $$
  On the other hand, $(E \cap X_n) \subset X_n$. So
  $$
  \begin{align}
  \mu^* (E \cap X_n ) &= \mu^*((E\cap X_n) \cap A') +\mu^*((E\cap X_n) \cap (X_n \setminus A')) \\
  &= \mu^*(E\cap A') +\mu^*((E\cap X_n) \cap (X \setminus A')).
  \end{align}
  $$
  It follows that
  $$
  \begin{align}
  \mu^*(E)  &= \mu^*(E\cap A') +\mu^*((E\cap X_n) \cap (X \setminus A')) +\mu^*(E\cap (X \setminus X_n)) \\
  &= \mu^*(E\cap A') +\mu^*(E \cap (X_n \setminus A')) +\mu^*(E\cap (X \setminus X_n)) \\
  &\ge \mu^*(E\cap A') +\mu^*( [E \cap (X_n \setminus A')] \cup [E\cap (X \setminus X_n)]) \\
  &= \mu^*(E\cap A') +\mu^*( E \cap [(X_n \setminus A') \cup (X \setminus X_n)]) \\
  &= \mu^*(E\cap A') +\mu^*( E \cap (X \setminus A')).
  \end{align}
  $$

$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

---

**Proof of Lemma** Fix $A \subset X_n$. First,
$$
\begin{align}
\mu_n^*(A) &= \inf \left\{ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \mu_n (B_m) : (B_m) \subset \mathcal X_n , A \subset \bigcup_m B_m \right\} \\
&= \inf \left\{ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \mu (B_m) : (B_m) \subset \mathcal X_n , A \subset \bigcup_m B_m \right\} \text{ because } \mu_n = \mu |_{\mathcal X_n}\\
&\ge \inf \left\{ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \mu (B_m) : (B_m) \subset \mathcal X , A \subset \bigcup_m B_m \right\} \\
&= \mu^* (A).
\end{align}
$$

Second,
$$
\begin{align}
\mu^*(A) &= \inf \left\{ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \mu (B_m) : (B_m) \subset \mathcal X , A \subset \bigcup_m B_m \right\} \\
&\ge \inf \left\{ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \mu (B_m \cap X_n) : (B_m) \subset \mathcal X , A \subset \bigcup_m B_m \right\}\\
&\ge \inf \left\{ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \mu_n (B_m) : (B_m) \subset \mathcal X_n , A \subset \bigcup_m B_m \right\} \\
&= \mu_n^* (A).
\end{align}
$$

$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

Comment: Very nicely written proofs! I have two questions: 1) The results seem to be concerned with only one $X_n$, so why is it necessary that $(X_n)$ is a pairwise disjoint sequence? 2) In the 2nd line from the last (in the proof of the Lemma), isn't it an equality instead of an inequality?

Comment: @ashpool Yes, (1) the fact that $(X_n)$ are pairwise disjoint is irrelevant. (2) Because $A \subset X_n$, that inequality is equivalent to
$$
\begin{align*}
& \inf \left\{ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \mu (B_m \cap X_n) : (B_m) \subset \mathcal X , A \subset \bigcup_m (B_m \cap X_n) \right\}\\
\ge & \inf \left\{ \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \mu (C_m) : (C_m) \subset \mathcal X_n , A \subset \bigcup_m C_m \right\}.
\end{align*}
$$
[...]

Comment: [...] To prove it, I used the trivial fact that
$$
\left\{ (B_m \cap X_n)_m :(B_m) \subset \mathcal X , A \subset \bigcup_m (B_m \cap X_n) \right\} \subset \left\{  (C_m) \subset \mathcal X_n , A \subset \bigcup_m C_m \right\}.
$$

I don't know how to prove the reverse inclusion.

Comment: Yes, although there may be a proper inclusion of sets, I thought the set of the sums is the same... Anyhow, this does not affect the conclusion of your proofs; I went over your proofs and I found no errors. They were very good, too, and helped me a lot. Thanks!

Comment: @ashpool Glad that it helps.